# How to get the text on the border of collapsable panel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Please advice how to get border to a collapsable panel.I was not able to use fieldset here.My code for panel and button is as below:

```
 <div>
                        <!-- Trigger Button HTML -->
                        <input type="button" id="collapsible1" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myCollapsible1" value="+" /> Primary Keys
                        <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
                        <div id="myCollapsible1" class="collapse" style="padding:30px;font-family:arial;font-size:15px;background: #eee;border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 20px 0;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but maybe you want to check the 'toggle' feature. You want the fieldset to be hidden when you click the 'left-top' button, right? Check this `data-toggle="collapse"`

This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible&stacked=h) might give some perspective.

Comment: Sure, Will check. This is what I have <div>
                            <!-- Trigger Button HTML -->
                            <input type="button" id="collapsible1" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myCollapsible1" value="+" /> Primary Keys
                            <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
                            <div id="myCollapsible1" class="collapse" style="padding:30px;font-family:arial;font-size:15px;background: #eee;border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 20px 0;">
   </div>
                        </div>

Comment: I referred those articles and wrote the above one.